# Why does the click event not fire on my SVG group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, onclick

I have an **svg file** (a world map) with **path**s that shape every single country, which themselves are grouped in **g** elements which represent the continents - structured like this:

```
<svg id="worldmap" viewBox="100 0 8334 4171">
  <g id="Asia" class="wm-cont">
    <path id="AF" d="M5707.92,1390.83l-22.5, etc...
    ...
```

I would like to zoom in on a continent once it's clicked, so I wrote the following jQuery for Asia:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Asia").click(function() {

        // hide all continents
        $(".wm-cont").css("display", "none");

        // show Asia
        $("g.wm-cont#Asia").fadeIn();

        // shift the continent into view
        $("g.wm-cont#Asia").setAttribute("transform", "translate(-400,439) scale(0.032,-0.032");
    });
});
```

... but I click and nothing happens. Why not? I tried altering my selectors to g#Asia and similar ones, but nothing changed.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

---

### Update

For some reason, now this worked:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Asia', function() {
    alert("Asia");
});
```

... although I didn't change anything in the structure of the svg. Any idea about why this works is warmly welcome :-)

Answer (score 3):

A `g` element is just an empty container; it can not fire events by itself.
put `rect` in your `g` and try

```
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" fill= "white" height="100"></rect>
```

example demo

```js
document.querySelector("#Asia").addEventListener("click", () => alert("clicked"))
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <g id="Asia">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" fill= "gray" height="100"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - I only don't understand, my `<g id="Asia>` encases a great number of paths which themselves have fill values (given by css), so the area is not empty. Does that still make that big a difference?